# visual studio runs as administrator, even when told not to

Tags: visual-studio-2010, privileges

I was having some issues with Quickbooks integration when running visual studio as administrator (which I had set as default), so I went in and turned it off. (Properties, security, advanced, uncheck "run as administrator".

That didn't work, so I did the same for the executable (devenv.exe). This worked initially, but after a reboot it's back to running as administrator again. I can't get it to run as non-admin at all. Is there a way to force it to run as a normal user?

Comment: What operating system are you using, and which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: @ƉiamondǤeezeƦ Windows 8, VS2010 v10.0.40219 SP1

Answer (score 2):

Check whether your shortcut to Visual Studio has starts with: `C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe`

[image: Shortcut Properties Dialog]

Comment: I checked that too. It's not in there. Sorry, I meant to put that in the question body.